Python 3.12.4 and easygui 0.98.3
I have been using python since a year now. I had an older version of it, with which I have written some code. Furthermore, I use 'easygui' for file browser. Every this was working well till I updated python to 3.12.4. Now, trying to run my code it gives the error:
- ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'easygui'.
I can not roll back the python version as I want to deploy the code on cloud and changes I have made for same requires 3.12.4.
Currently, I have the following installed:

python 3.12.4.
easygui 0.98.3.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling 'easygui'. But no change or improvement. Any other solution?

0.98.3 is the last version of easygui. You an specify an older version with pip install easygui==version and add it to your requierments.txt if needed.
Another thing you may can do is patching the module making your own version by forking and patching the source code

older versions are not supported either. I am not aware how to patch/fork.

Well it is a complex task, especially if you're new to Python, as it involves downloading the source code and creating your own version. The best thing you can do might be to create an issue on their GitHub repository, explaining the problem you're encountering:  https://github.com/aroberge/easygui_qt/issues/new
